# Layout corrupt after scalling the fonts in all browsers

Tags: css, layout, scaling, font-size

Below is the simple layout. I need help with this because when I scaling the font in browsers by pressing CTRL and scrolling up (zooming) then this this layout dont behave like I expected.

What I want is that #allWrapper should scale its dimensions with body so the white background will be on the all width. If You zoom font enough and horizontal scroll bar appear then try to scroll to the right and You will notice that the allWrapper is smaller than body and color of the body is showing instead of white. I cant make body white because footer will be in this color too (not white). Here is the short code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">
div,body{margin: 0;padding: 0;border: 0;font-size: 100%;font: inherit;vertical-align: baseline;}
body{font-family:Arial,sans-serif;background-color:#066789;}
#allWrapper{background-color:white;}
#header .content {height:90px;background-color:white; position:relative;}
#mainWrapper{margin-top:0.5em; line-height:1.5;}
.center {width:980px;margin:0px auto;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="allWrapper">
<div id="header">
    <div class="center">
        <div class="content">
        HEADER
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <div id="mainWrapper">
        <div class="center">
            <div class="content">MAIN CONTENT</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to `#allWrapper`:

```
min-width:980px;
```

The issue is the `html`/`body` elements are 100% of the visible screen (not the entire layout) and `#allWrapper` is staying contained within those. The same problem can be seen if the browser is resized to a size less wide than 980px. By adding the `min-width` to `#allWrapper`, it forces `#allWrapper` to stay as wide as the contained box. If you prefer, `min-width` could be added to `body` instead.

Comment: My Master!!! It works great but I didn't understand why :) #allWrapper contains all other elements. Other elements inside #allWrapper are resizing. Other elements inside those elements resizing good to so I wonder why external element #allWrapper didn't resize like others. Thank You very much.

Comment: @Marcin, only .center is resized correctly. Its ancestors, however, are not (`#mainWrapper`, `#content`, and `#allWrapper`). They are all contained within `body`. The joys of CSS :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a percentage instead of exact pixels, in this case.

Like this:

```
.center {width:80%;margin:0px auto;}
```

Comment: I need exacly the 980px in this layout.

Comment: If you need an exact pixel amount... the viewing pixel size is still going to change once a user zooms in, right?  Percentages often prevent having that scrollbar appear when zoomed in, as well.

Comment: Yes of course but when I enter to the site in zoom set to normal (CTRL+0) then it must be in 980px. When I zooming the width is changing, the body width is changing but the #addWrapper width isn't changing like body width.

Comment: Check out @bfrohs' answer if you want pixels here.